# How to generate links to envelope web UI

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on application that needs to include links to an envelope that was created in response to an event. Because the link is going to be displayed to potentially multiple users in a separate interface, most with less DocuSign privileges than the account that will authorize the ouauth grant we can not use things like SenderView. The URL needs to be valid for as long as the envelope status does not change.

We are currently hard-coding the URLs (with dynamic envelope ID) like so: `https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents/details/{envelope_id}` the users would then be prompted to sign into their DocuSign account before viewing the envelope. Which is fine for our use-case.

This has a number problems:

1. the path is hard-coded with no guarantees that it will not be broken with future updates to the DocuSign web UI
2. The base domain is hard-coded which means that we have to make sure to change it between dev and production versions

I am not sure that there's anything that can be done for the first other than quickly reacting to such changes when or if they occurs.

The second one is a bigger concern for us. After seeing that SenderView uses the web UI domain we tried to create a SenderView just to extract the domain to solve the hard-coded issue and hopefully guard against DocuSign Brands potentially allowing custom domains.

It seems that the domain in the URL of a SenderView depends on the envelope status. Most of them seem to use the API domain (https://demo.docusign.net) which we can extract via the userinfo endpoint, but it doesn't always correctly redirect to the web UI

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you do instead is build your own web app that has it's own view that includes a parameter with envelopeId passed to it.

Your server code then does the logic to figure out everything needed for the user.
You can either show the user a custom web view that gives them information about the envelope or take them directly to the signing view or the tagger - you have full control.

See [How to embed the DocuSign UI in your application](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embed-ui/)

Also see [How to send an envelope via your app](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/)

To figure out the baseUrl you can use the [User Info endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/)

Comment: 1. App is being built to a customer's spec and custom management UI is way out of scope

2. BaseUri reported by user info endpoint is not usable for the type of URL we're trying to generate

3. SenderView has unacceptable security implications that are described in the original post

Comment: What are the security implication of the SenderView?

Comment: "This method provides full access to the sending account. When you use this view, the current user has full access to the account. If the account has administrative privileges, then this method also provides administrator access."

Comment: Where is this quote from? I am 95% certain this is wrong, it is talking about a bug that was since fixed. Can you show me where you see this?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createcorrect/ ok, let me track this down, this may or may not be correct, I didn't realize you were talking about the Correct view, which is different than senderView

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/ that's the one I meant for you to use, and it does NOT have this security issue.

Comment: Both have the same security notice

Comment: This issue will be fixed soon, I don't have an ETA, but I know this is in the works

Comment: @InbarGazit are you able to provide any ticket/reference numbers we could use to chase this up via our partner contacts?